# connection to oracle db on same network

Tags: php, oracle

this is my php code to connect to oracle 11.2 g db on my university network
 but it does not work proprly.

here is the code

```
<? php

 $conn = oci_connect('usename', 'password', 'ics-db.ccse.kfupm.edu.sa:1521/XE'); 

                if (!$conn) {

                 $e = oci_error();
                   echo "Couldn't make a connection!";              
 }
         else
       $stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM student');
       oci_execute($stid);
       echo "<table border='1'>\n";
   while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
        echo "<tr>\n";
         foreach ($row as $item) {
       echo "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) :  "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";


     }
 echo "</tr>\n";
  }

       echo "</table>\n";

     oci_close($stid);

                           ?>
```

this is what will be printed on the webpage which is not right

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {

echo "<tr>\n";

foreach ($row as $item) {

echo "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you've left a space between the opening tag and the php, and some missing brackets code should read:

```html
<?php

 $conn = oci_connect('usename', 'password', 'ics-db.ccse.kfupm.edu.sa:1521/XE'); 

                if (!$conn) {

                 $e = oci_error();
                   echo "Couldn't make a connection!";              
 }
        else{
  
       $stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM student');
       oci_execute($stid);
       echo "<table border='1'>\n";
    while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
         echo "<tr>\n";
           foreach ($row as $item) {
         echo "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) :  "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";
     }
 echo "</tr>\n";
  }
}

       echo "</table>\n";

     oci_close($stid);

 ?>
```

Probably worth using a code editor which will highlight these problems such as Notepad++ (free).

Comment: There's not open bracket after the else either, I would test your connection (use var_dump) and then start to introduce the lines after the else one by one.

Comment: What is the result of the var_dump?  If you've started introducing the lines one by one it can't be the same, are you using an IDE to catch syntax errors?